# When I run my autoclicker I can't stop it

Tags: java, windows, swing

If I click on start button I can't click back or stop. I need to stop the app. One way to stop the app is that you must power off computer :D. When the app is running, start button is locked and I can't click on it. Click on the exit button doesn't work. This app is simple AutoClicker. Exist in java something better to do autoclicker than robot class? How can I fix it? Is there error anywhere? Or is there something I can do to stop the app?

```
 import java.awt.AWTException;
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.EventQueue;
 import java.awt.Robot;

 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
 import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;

 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 import java.awt.Color;


public class AutoClicker extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private final JLabel m = new JLabel("AutoClicker");

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AutoClicker frame = new AutoClicker();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public AutoClicker() {

    setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    setTitle("AutoClicker");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 147, 162);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JCheckBox chckbxOnTop = new JCheckBox("On Top");
     boolean onTop = false;
    chckbxOnTop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            if(chckbxOnTop.isSelected()){
                setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            }
            else{
                setAlwaysOnTop(false);
            }   

        }
    });
    chckbxOnTop.setBounds(6, 7, 97, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxOnTop);




    JCheckBox chckbxAutoclicker = new JCheckBox("AutoClicker");
    chckbxAutoclicker.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            while(chckbxAutoclicker.isSelected()){

                        try {
                            Robot r = new Robot();
                            r.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                            r.setAutoDelay(1080);
                            r.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                        } catch (AWTException e1) {

                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }



    });
    chckbxAutoclicker.setBounds(6, 80, 97, 23);
    contentPane.add(chckbxAutoclicker);
    m.setForeground(new Color(153, 102, 0));
    m.setBounds(16, 92, 120, 31);
    contentPane.add(m);
}
}
```

Comment: why are you using two nested infinite loops? And why the hell are you using `for(;;)` instead of `while (something)`? And what do you expect your program to do other than hang up everything?

Comment: When i remove two for loops and add one while loop it cant be closed/stoped.

Comment: you are not even trying to stop it

Comment: Sorry i edit currect code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is single threaded - calling any long running task on that thread will lock that thread up (the EDT) and prevent any painting, events, etc... from occurring. One of the `ActionListener` implementations creates an infinite loop:

```
while(chckbxAutoclicker.isSelected()){
```

The above will never evaluate to false, because it is evaluating on the EDT, and events (such as disabling the `JCheckBox` to allow this method to return false) cannot occur until the EDT is free. If you wish to continually run a task while allowing the EDT to performs its necessary tasks, you have three options:

1. Create a new [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Note any calls to Swing from this thread should be dispatched to the EDT using `SwingUtilities.invoke*`
2. Use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)
3. If you wish to do something at a later time on the EDT, or run something on a schedule on the EDT, use a [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)